# Is this a genre, a plot template or something else?

Tags: analysis, genre

I've stumbled upon (and watched) a number of films that share many things: *Divergent*, *The Maze Runner*, *The Giver* and so on (I will add as I recall othrs that I've seen and from comments).

These movies all share these common elements:

- a (more or less futuristic) social community with a (more or less) dystopic leader/government (in or outside of said community)
- strong factions/caste/districts/teams/houses divisions that most people are assigned to; the main character often is given some sort of choice because reasons (divergent) or assigned to "special" faction (jonas the giver, for example)
- a final "mindblowing" (often sci-fi) plot twist (commonly: "it was an experiment") revealing how the world they lived in was fake/planned/controlled.

**Is this kind of "optimized plot" an industry standard?**

These are all films targeted at teenagers, and, for example, the factions create sense of belonging.

Are there any other recognized plot patterns that enhance appreciation, for other target audiences like this (in my opinion) does?

---

*This quote from Homer Simpon inspired this question, so I will put it here, altought it is not part of the question.*

> **Homer Simpson**: Finally a movie about a dystopian future, unlike *The
>   Hunger Games, Edge of Tomorrow, Oblivion, Elysium, Snowpiercer, The
>   Hunger Games: Catching Fire, X-Men: Days of Future Past, Ender's Game,
>   The Road, World War Z, Children of Men, After Earth, I Am Legend, Mad
>   Max: Fury Road, The Maze Runner, District 9, The Purge, Looper, Cloud
>   Atlas, Divergent, Insurgent, The Island, Mr. Burns: A Post-Electric
>   Play,* and *Chappie.*

Comment: Surely this is typical of hundreds of films starting with Metropolis in 1926.

Comment: Those I reported are pretty much *the same* films, except the story setting and some minor things

Comment: You missed Logan's Run & 1984 ;)

Comment: Maybe you find something which applies [on tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HelpHelpThisIndexIsBeingRepressed)?

Comment: I think that teenage dystopian sci-fi would be a genre of its own, and the other common elements would be tropes of that genre.

Comment: A lot of those are adaptions to young adults novels where that's a common theme, and there's a lot more, The Host, The Mortal Instruments, Beautiful Creatures, Vampire Academy, The 5th Wave  and a lot of tv shows

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/2241.YA_Novels_Made_Into_Movies

Comment: Personally I classify it as postapocalyptic/dystopian subgenre of [young-adult fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young-adult_fiction).

Comment: The first two bullet points don't relate to plot, but the third is what's often called a "plot point".  See my answer below on story structure for answers to your questions regarding plot and formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Q: Is this kind of optimized plot an industry standard?*

This is a great question!

Major studios don't like to take risks, so they favor reusing formulas that are proven to work. (This is partly to do with the massive risk undertaken in producing high-budget films. Opening weekend numbers can actually affect the stock price of major corporations.)

*Q: Are there any other recognized plot patterns that enhance appreciation, for other target audiences like this (in my opinion) does?*

There a literally volumes and volumes about story structure in screenplays, and it's part art, part science.

[This link](http://www.storymastery.com/story/screenplay-structure-five-key-turning-points-successful-scripts/) is quite interesting and useful as it shows how both **Gladiator** and **Erin Brokovich** have the same story structure.

[The Wikipedia entry on the three-act structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-act_structure) will also be enlightening, particularly as you can click to other important concepts.